# using dao and transfer object with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'd like to write an application using Hibernate. I know that normally it is a good idea to write a DAO object for database access.

So that means that I add the persistence annotations to my model classes and then pass that model do the DAO implementation class for that model and in the DAO implementation class I write the actual hibernate code, right?

Do I still need or is it a good idea to use a transfer object? I thought about it and wouldnt I have to also annotate the transfer object? Because ultimately I would pass the transfer object to the DAO implementation class, right? But that class needs an annotated object to pass to the hibernate code.

So is the transfer object superfluous when using hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "transfer object". You want to persist your model classes. Those need annotation and those need DAO's.

Transfer objects are objects you want to show in the frontend. For example, a model class `Teacher` might have a name, salary and ID. But in your frontend, you will only show a name and salary. the transfer object doesn't need the ID.

Comment: Er... arent transfer objects used to minimize calls to the database? So instead of persisting everything individually, I collect it in a transfer object and then only persist that? See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: I've got no clue what you're saying. Please elaborate with an example.

Comment: Well, what you're saying about transfer objects is something completely different from the transfer objects mentioned in the wikipedia article. Maybe we're talking about different things? Where in the wikipedia article does it say anything about frontends?